# Magento 2 recommended approach to applying patches

Tags: magento2, patches, security

So far had to apply patches through command line. Bugs me there is not version control for this as in some cases changing vendor folder contents which is ignored. More for accountability with time and date of change instead of ability to revert. But then I came across this article.

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005484154-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit

Its hard to gauge from this article. Is this the recommended approach to applying patches? Or is there another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that there doesn't seem to be a recommended approach for this. I believe the magento team would prefer store owners keep their stores up to date with rolling releases via composer update.

This is fine with a vanilla store. But a store with lots of extensions this may be too ambitious.